# Smooth/histogram a 2D set

Tags: list-manipulation, histograms

I have a 2D dataset like this one: `{{x1,y1}, {x2,y2},...}`
I need to smooth/histogram the data in such a way that binning is over the x-coordinate, while counting/height is over the y-coordinate. Let me explain.

Given the following input, `bin-width = 0.2` and `height-function = Mean[]`.

```
data = {{0.1,1.0}, {0.2,2.0}, {0.3,3.0}, {0.35,3.5}, {0.4,4.0}, {0.5,5.0}};
```

The output would be:

```
{(1 + 2)/2, (3 + 3.5 + 4)/3, 5/1}
```

The average of y-values from the first two data points goes into the first bin, the following three points form the second bin etc...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's start with your sample data:

```
In[1]:= data = {{0.1, 1.0}, {0.2, 2.0}, {0.3, 3.0}, {0.35, 3.5}, {0.4, 4.0}, {0.5, 5.0}};
```

First we can use [`GatherBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GatherBy.html) to group entries by bin:

```
In[2]:= GatherBy[data, Ceiling[First[#], 0.2] &]

Out[2]= {{{0.1, 1.}, {0.2, 2.}}, {{0.3, 3.}, {0.35, 3.5}, {0.4, 4.}}, {{0.5, 5.}}}
```

Then select the second element of each pair (`Last`) and calculate the means:

```
In[3]:= Mean[Last /@ #] & /@ %

Out[3]= {1.5, 3.5, 5.}
```

Comment: This method groups elements `0.29` and `0.31` -- shouldn't these be in separate bins?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No, because with a bin size of 0.2 everything between 0.2 and 0.4 should be in the same bin.  I just realized though that `$MachineEpsilon` is too small a number to add here if the $x$-values are greater than 1.  (I added a note about this.)

Comment: If that is the intent couldn't you use `Ceiling[#, 0.2]`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, you are right, I fixed it.

Comment: Voted.  If the OP actually wants bins to `0.1, 0.3, 0.5` which was my own reading, this is more complicated I think.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard that's how I understood the question as well. You could

Answer (score 6):

I propose:

```
data = {{0.1, 1.0}, {0.2, 2.0}, {0.3, 3.0}, {0.35, 3.5}, {0.4, 4.0}, {0.5, 5.0}};

Mean /@ Reap[#2 ~Sow~ Ceiling[#, 0.2] & @@@ data][[2]]
```

> ```
> {1.5, 3.5, 5.}
> ```

Comment: +1 I had almost forgotten the "~ ~ ~ ~ " war :)

Comment: @belisarius I actually started without that but then I decided to keep up my end of the game. :^)

Answer (score 4):

Another offering making use of `BinLists`:

```
data = {{0.1, 1.0}, {0.2, 2.0}, {0.3, 3.0}, {0.35, 3.5}, {0.4, 
    4.0}, {0.5, 5.0}};

Smoothed[data_, binSize_] := 
 With[{xs = data\[Transpose] // First, ys = data\[Transpose] // Last},
   Mean@ys[[#]] & /@ (Flatten[Map[Position[xs, #] &, #]] & /@ 
     BinLists[xs, 0.2 + $MachineEpsilon])]

Smoothed[data, 0.2]

(* ->  {1.5, 3.5, 5.}  *)
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to use `BinLists`:

```
Mean /@ (Join @@ BinLists[data, .2 + $MachineEpsilon,
  Max[data[[All, 2]]] + 1][[All, All, All, -1]])
```

> {1.5, 3.5, 5.}