# Displaying a list of percentage values according to their classification

Tags: list-manipulation, output-formatting

I have a list of percentages as follows:

```
percent = 
  {21.15, 42.3, 57.68, 73.06, 84.6, 90.37, 96.14, 99.99, 99.99, 99.99, 99.99}
```

I want to classify these percentages into categories A, B and C. When a value is in the range 0% - 85%, it is A; when it in the range 85% - 95%, it is B; when it in the range 95% - 100%, it is C.

For example: elements 1, 2, 3 and 4 of `percent` should all be classified into the A category.

How might I produce a `TableForm` showing all the elements in `percent` displayed according to category?

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89438/cumulative-probability-about-the-number-of-variable-abc-analyse -- same numbers, too!

Comment: Proposed duplicate: [(36867)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/36867/121).  Related: [(5289)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5289/121)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
percent = 
  {21.15, 42.3, 57.68, 73.06, 84.6, 90.37, 96.14, 99.99, 99.99, 99.99, 99.99};

{{"A", "B", "C"}, 
  GatherBy[percent, {# <= 85, # <= 95, # <= 100} &]} // TableForm
```

[image]

This can also be written as

```
{{"A", "B", "C"}, 
  GatherBy[percent, Thread[# <= {85, 95, 100}] &]} // TableForm
```

Comment: Elegant solution!

Answer (score 8):

Depending on how you want the table aligned, you could use

```
percent = 
  {21.15, 42.3, 57.68, 73.06, 84.6, 90.37, 96.14, 99.99, 99.99, 99.99, 99.99};

TableForm[BinLists[percent, {{0., 85., 95., 100.}}], 
  TableHeadings -> {{"A", "B", "C"}}]
```

[image: hz]

or

```
TableForm[{{"A", "B", "C"}, BinLists[percent, {{0., 85., 95., 100.}}]},
  TableAlignments -> {Center, Top}]
```

[image: vt]