# Split list based on positions contained in another list

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, recursion, gathering

### The problem

Suppose that after importing several files into my nb (x-y dataset, but this procedure should work also for x-y-z datasets), I end up with a nested list similar to:

```
file01 = {{0.1, 1}, {0.2, 2}, {0.3, 3}, {0.4, 4}, {0.5, 5}};
file02 = {{0.1, 10}, {0.2, 20}, {0.3, 30}, {0.4, 40}, {0.5, 50}};
file03 = ..;
data = {file01, file02, file03, ..};
```

The data are x-sorted and unique.

I would like to split each `file0i` into sublists by comparing its x-values with some ranges contained in a different list, let's say:

```
ranges = {0.15, 0.25, 0.45};
```

The list `ranges` applies to all files, is not empty, sorted and does not exceed the  x-values of each `file0i`-sublist.

The result I'm expecting should be:

```
splitData[data, ranges]
(*
{
  {
    {{0.1, 1}, {0.2, 2}},
    {{0.2, 2}, {0.3, 3}},
    {{0.3, 3}, {0.4, 4}, {0.5, 5}},
    {{0.5, 5}}
  },
  {
    {{0.1, 1}, {0.2, 2}},
    {{0.2, 2}, {0.3, 3}},
    {{0.3, 3}, {0.4, 4}, {0.5, 5}},
    {{0.5, 5}}
  }
}
*)
```

I do want the last and the first element of two consecutive sublists to be the same (for later use with `ListPlot`).

---

### My solution

My idea was to develop a procedure that works for a single `file0i`-sublist and apply it later to all other sublists.

1. Find the first position at which the x-values of one `file0i`-sublist exceed the different values of `ranges`.

   ```
   Clear@findPositionSingleList;
   findPositionSingleList::usage = 
     "findPositionSingleList[ranges][list] finds the positions in
     list={{x1,y1},{x2,y2},..} where its x-element exceeds for the
     first time the values of ranges={X1,X2,..}. `list` can be a list
     of {x,y,z} values too.
     Example: findPositionSingleList[{1,5}][{{1,3},{2,4},{3,5},{6,7}}] = {2,4}";

   findPositionSingleList[ranges_List][list_List] := 
     Flatten@Outer[FirstPosition[x_ /; x > #1][#2] &, 
        ranges, {list[[All, 1]]}, 1] /. {x_} -> x;
   ```

   For example:

   ```
   findPositionSingleList[ranges][file01]
   (*{2, 3, 5}*)
   ```

   I was unable to get rid of the extra curly braces `{list[[All, 1]]}` in the function `findPositionSingleList` in order to make `Outer` work properly.
2. Split a single `file0i`-sublist using the positions calculated with `findPositionSingleList`:

   ```
     Clear@splitSingleList;
     splitSingleList::usage = 
       "splitSingleList[list_List,positions_List] = split `list` into
       sublists at the positions contained in positions.
       Example: splitList[{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h},{2,3}] =
                {{a,b},{b,c},{c,d,e,f,g,h}}";

     splitSingleList[list_List, position_List] := Block[
       {iter},
       iter[l_List, pos_List, acc_: {}] :=
        If[Length@pos == 1,
         Join[acc, {l[[First@pos ;; -1]]}],
         iter[l, Rest@pos, Join[acc, {l[[pos[[1]] ;; pos[[2]]]]}]]
         ];
       Join[{list[[1 ;; First@position]]},
        iter[list, position] ]
       ]
   ```
3. Now I can combine the two functions:

   ```
     Clear@splitDataSingleList;
     splitDataSingleList[ranges_List][list_List] := 
      splitSingleList[#1, findPositionSingleList[#2][#1]] & @@ {list, ranges}
   ```

   When evaluated I get:

   ```
     splitDataSingleList[ranges][file01]
     (*
     {
       {{0.1, 1}, {0.2, 2}},
       {{0.2, 2}, {0.3, 3}},
       {{0.3, 3}, {0.4, 4}, {0.5, 5}},
       {{0.5, 5}}
     }
     *)
   ```
4. I can now easily extend the procedure over all sublists:

   ```
     Clear@splitData
     splitData[data_List, ranges_List] := splitDataSingleList[ranges] /@ data
         (*
         {
           {
             {{0.1, 1}, {0.2, 2}},
             {{0.2, 2}, {0.3, 3}},
             {{0.3, 3}, {0.4, 4}, {0.5, 5}},
             {{0.5, 5}}
           },
           {
             {{0.1, 1}, {0.2, 2}},
             {{0.2, 2}, {0.3, 3}},
             {{0.3, 3}, {0.4, 4}, {0.5, 5}},
             {{0.5, 5}}
           }
         }
         *)
   ```

---

### My question

The procedure does what I want (I couldn't spot any side effects until now), but I was wondering if there's something that I can do to improve my code style (new built-in functions? better pattern-matching? maybe use `Fold` instead of the recursive function?).

Cheers.

Comment: Related: [(5289)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5289/121), [(33153)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33153/121), [(36867)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/36867/121), [(46972)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46972/121), [(50559)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/50559/121)

Answer (score 5):

Your approach is good, but you didn't find the simplest implementation. Here is another way:

```
ranges = {0.15, 0.25, 0.45, 0.5};

split[list_, cutoff_] := TakeDrop[list, LengthWhile[list, First[#] <= cutoff &]]
append[{list1_, list2_}] := Append[list1, First[list2]]
append[{list1_, {}}] := list1

FoldPairList[split, file01, ranges, append]
(*
{{{0.1, 1}, {0.2, 2}}, {{0.2, 2}, {0.3, 3}}, {{0.3, 3}, {0.4, 4}, {0.5, 5}}, {{0.5, 5}}}
*)
```

I added the largest x value to `ranges`, you can find it by using `Max` on the list of values if you don't know it.

Comment: Simple and elegant solution! Never heard about `TakeDrop` and `FoldPairList`. Thanks, @C.E.!

Answer (score 5):

Superseding my earlier answer I think I have a very pleasing solution using [`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html) and [`Reap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html).

No need for [`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html) or [`Cases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html) in this code.  This is not quite as fast however.

```
split2[r_List, p_: 1][a_List] :=
  Module[{i = 1, rr = Append[r, ∞]},
    a
     // Scan[Sow[#, i] || #[[p]] <= rr[[i]] || Sow[#, ++i] &]
     // Reap
     // Last
  ]
```

---

In version 10.1.0 I have neither [`TakeDrop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TakeDrop.html) nor [`FoldPairList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldPairList.html) so here is a method with [`Split`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Split.html).

```
split[r_List, p_: 1][a_List] :=
  Module[{i = 1, rr = Append[r, ∞]},
    Split[a, #2[[p]] <= rr[[i]] || i++ &]
     // Partition[#, 2, 1, 1, {}] &
     // Cases[{{x__}, {y_, ___}} | {{x___}} :> {x, y}]
  ]
```

Test:

```
file01 = {{0.1, 1}, {0.2, 2}, {0.3, 3}, {0.4, 4}, {0.5, 5}};
file02 = {{0.1, 10}, {0.2, 20}, {0.3, 30}, {0.4, 40}, {0.5, 50}};
ranges = {0.15, 0.25, 0.45};

split[ranges] /@ {file01, file02}
```

> ```
> {
>  {
>   {{0.1, 1}, {0.2, 2}},
>   {{0.2, 2}, {0.3, 3}},
>   {{0.3, 3}, {0.4, 4}, {0.5, 5}},
>   {{0.5, 5}}
>  },
>  {
>   {{0.1, 10}, {0.2, 20}},
>   {{0.2, 20}, {0.3, 30}},
>   {{0.3, 30}, {0.4, 40}, {0.5, 50}},
>   {{0.5, 50}}
>  }
> }
> ```

Are all lists to be split exactly the same? If so it will be faster to generate indexes for one and apply it to all, rather than splitting each list separately.

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Wizard: love the combination of `SplitBy` and `Partition`. Unfortunately I do not know in advance the length of each list, only its structure, so I cannot leverage the index-functionality. However, I will keep it in mind for future challenges!

Comment: @MrG You're welcome.  In testing `Split` seems to be faster here so I used that instead.  Also I had a bug I fixed by appending Infinity to the range list.

Comment: @MrG Please see the new method I placed at the top of my answer.  I think it works correctly; if not let me know.

Answer (score 5):

Processing the output of `BinLists` with appropriate bin specifications:

```
ClearAll[f]
f[r_] := With[{bl = BinLists[#, {Flatten@{-∞, r, ∞}}, {{-∞, ∞}}][[All, 1]]}, 
   Append[BlockMap[Join[#[[1]], {#[[2, 1]]}] &, bl, 2, 1], bl[[-1]]]] &;
```

Examples:

```
 file01 = {{0.1, 1}, {0.2, 2}, {0.3, 3}, {0.4, 4}, {0.5, 5}};
 file02 = {{0.1, 10}, {0.2, 20}, {0.3, 30}, {0.4, 40}, {0.5, 50}};
 ranges = {0.15, 0.25, 0.45}; 

 f[ranges]/@ {file01, file02}

{  
   {  
    {{0.1, 1}, {0.2, 2}},  
    {{0.2, 2}, {0.3, 3}},  
    {{0.3, 3}, {0.4, 4}, {0.5, 5}},  
    {{0.5, 5}}  
   },  
   {  
    {{0.1, 10}, {0.2, 20}},  
    {{0.2, 20}, {0.3, 30}},  
    {{0.3, 30}, {0.4, 40}, {0.5, 50}},  
    {{0.5, 50}}  
   }  
 }
```

For 9th and earlier versions you can use `` Developer`PartitionMap `` instead of `BlockMap`.

Comment: thanks for your solution! `BinLists` and `PartitionMap` are new to me.

Comment: `BlockMap` can replace `PartitionMap` if one wants something documented.

Comment: Thank you @C.E. Updated with your suggestion.